# Python time greeting program

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to create a program that greats users base on the time of the day but when I run my code I get this error:
    unorderable types: str() < int()

I dont think I'm doing it the right way and I cant figure out a better way to do it, so are the better ways to write this program???

Here is my Code:

```
import time
currentTime = time.strftime('%H:%M')   

if currentTime.hour < 12 :
     print('Good morning')
if currentTime.hour > 12 :
     print('Good afternoon')
if currentTime.hour > 6 :
     print('Good evening')
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you're using? I get an error from `currentTime.hour`, since that attribute doesn't exist. `time.strftime` on my Python returns a string, so not having time-specific attributes doesn't surprise me. Are you looking for `datetime.now` or something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you want to work with objects that represent the time. I recommend the `datetime` module.

Also, your code assumes that the computer will guess whether the hour you entered is AM or PM. You would have to use an hour of `18` to represent 6:00 PM.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> currentTime.hour
0
>>> if currentTime.hour < 12:
...     print('Good morning.')
... elif 12 <= currentTime.hour < 18:
...     print('Good afternoon.')
... else:
...     print('Good evening.')
...
Good morning.
```

Answer (score 3):

I saw that the answers listed here were quite lengthy so created a more concise version for those that need it (even though this post is more than 2 years old).
However this top version may break the formatting outlined in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) because the third line goes over 80 characters (92), so feel free to use the longer version.

```
import datetime
hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
greeting = "Good morning" if 5<=hour<12 else "Good afternoon" if hour<18 else "Good evening"
```

Then use this wherever you need it...

```
print("{}!".format(greeting))
```

...or broken down for readability...

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
hour = now.hour

if hour < 12:
    greeting = "Good morning"
elif hour < 18:
    greeting = "Good afternoon"
else:
    greeting = "Good night"

print("{}!".format(greeting))
```

An example usage case would be saying a random 'goodbye' to make the program seem more lifelike. This would be done something like this...

```
import random, datetime
hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
greeting = "Have a nice day" if hour<20 else "Good night"
print(random.choice(["I look forward to our next meeting!",greeting+"!"]))
```

Comment: Why did you add `5 <=` that makes it say "Good afternoon" at three in the morning?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an attribute called `hour` in string variable.

```
import time
currentTime = int(time.strftime('%H'))   

if currentTime < 12 :
     print('Good morning')
if currentTime > 12 :
     print('Good afternoon')
if currentTime > 6 :
     print('Good evening')
```

Comment: thanks. I love the way you converted the current time into an integer, but I don't understand this part: .split(':')[0])

Comment: That is split the result according to `:`, and then get the 0th index of returned list.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=input("Enter your name:")

import datetime
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
currentTime.hour

if currentTime.hour < 12:
    print('Good morning',a)
elif 12 <= currentTime.hour < 18:
    print('Good afternoon',a)
else:
    print('Good evening',a)

[write this without using python,click this link provided below to write]
```

https://colab.research.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is not too late to give my contribution to this question:

```
from datetime import datetime

current_hour = int(datetime.now().strftime('%H'))
if current_hour<12:
    print('Good morning')
elif 12<=current_hour<18:
    print('Good afternoon')
else:
    print('Good Evening')
```

Answer (score 0):

The required functionality can be also acheived in a single line as follows

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> print(f"Good {['morning', 'morning', 'afternoon', 'evening'][int(datetime.datetime.now().hour/6)]}")
Good morning
```

Here, the hour is derived from `datetime.datetime.now().hour` and then used to determine the phase of the day.

The day is divided in four phases in which the first two phases are termed as morning, third as afternoon and fourth as evening.